# Why is Swift's fatalError's argument an @autoclosure?

Tags: swift

I was poking around Swift to find out that `fatalError` has this signature:

```
@noreturn public func fatalError(@autoclosure message: () -> String = default, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line)
```

Any specific reason as to why this function is defined this way? What is wrong with :

```
@noreturn public func fatalError(message:String = default, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    //Termination code
}
```

Note that I understand how `@autoclosure` works, and this question is not about its usage; but about the use-cases where such a pattern could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to optionally evaluate statement to reduce overhead.

For this code

```
fatalError("\(someExpansiveComputation())")
```

If the function is defined with normal parameter passing, then `someExpansiveComputation()` will always be called, even in production build.

However with `@autoclosure`, the implementation of `fatalError` can choose not call the closure, to avoid the overhead of calling `someExpansiveComputation()`

a possible implementation can be

```
@noreturn public func fatalError(message:String = default, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    if debug || errorReportingEnabled {
        log(message()) // only compute the message if necessary 
    }
    abort()
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. Any place I could find the actual implementation of `fatalError`? I have been searching in Swift's library for a while now. Could't find it.

Comment: That's interesting... The implementation of `fatalError` just calls `_assertionFailed` with `message()` as one of its arguments regardless of debugging mode. So it doesn't actually appear to be performance related... maybe it's just an oversight?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

To reduce the overheads of building an error message that will most likely not be displayed.

---

When you call the `fatalError` function there might be a lot of information going into building your error message. This can take a trivial amount of processing power and when it comes to a fatal error hopefully its not going to happen very often so it is optimal to only build the error message when you need to as opposed to building it up every time before the fatal error call is encountered and not even being put to use.

The `autoclosure` gives you the ability to provide the function with all the resources and instructions its needs to know on how to compose your error message without having to do all the work. When the fatal error function is called it will decide for itself whether it needs to call the provided closure to evaluate the string that it will print.